# How can I change the total sum in WooCommerce orders table?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to change the value of the `Total` field in the WooCommerce orders table:

[image]

I've got a function which checks some parameters. If these parameters are true, I need to set a custom value to the order like $50 instead of $60.

```
if ($is_valid == true) {
   //Change order value = $new_value;
}
```

Comment: Would that not be misleading? If an item is in the _orders table_, it means that someone has already purchased something for X price, therefore changing that value would create a discrepancy between what they paid and what their history shows that they paid?

Comment: I need to do this because I've a custom WooCommerce impl :